# PHP : file_get_contents with json_decode not working together

Tags: php, json

I have an issuse after reading json file with file_get_contents.

When I run this code, its working ok:

```
<?php
$json='[  
  {  
    "fullName":"Shachar Ganot",
    "address":"Yad Rambam",
    "phoneNumber":"050-1231233",
    "email":"",
    "note":"",
    "role":"",
    "area":""
  },
  {  
    "fullName":"Betty Ganot",
    "address":"Modiin",
    "phoneNumber":"054-3213211",
    "email":"",
    "note":"",
    "role":"",
    "area":""
  },
  {  
    "fullName":"Someone Else",
    "address":"Somewhere",
    "phoneNumber":"123456789",
    "email":"",
    "note":"",
    "role":"",
    "area":""
  }
]';

//$json = file_get_contents('Test.txt');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data[0]['fullName'];

?>
```

Result:
**Shachar Ganot**

When I run this code, its empty:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('Test.txt');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data[0]['fullName'];

?>
```

Result:
****Empty - Nothig appears****

when I run this code, to check if **file_get_contents** is working:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('Test.txt');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $json;

?>
```

Result:

[ { "fullName":"Shachar Ganot", "address":"Yad Rambam", "phoneNumber":"050-1231233", "email":"", "note":"", "role":"", "area":"" }, { "fullName":"Betty Ganot", "address":"Modiin", "phoneNumber":"054-3213211", "email":"", "note":"", "role":"", "area":"" }, { "fullName":"Someone Else", "address":"Somewhere", "phoneNumber":"123456789", "email":"", "note":"", "role":"", "area":"" } ]

---

What I'm missing??

Needless to say I did JSON Valid with https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your `Test.txt` is a encoded in UTF-8 ([with BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), the `json_decode` function will fail and return `NULL`.

You can fix this by fixing the content of your file, or trim the BOM from your `$json` string:

```
$json = trim(file_get_contents('Test.txt'), "\xEF\xBB\xBF");
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data[0]['fullName'];
```

> It will be much better to make sure the content of the file is correct and NOT use the trim function, unless you really have to.
>
> You can use [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) for example to change the from content from UTF-8 with BOM to UTF-8 Without BOM.

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 8.1 it is still not working.

For me it helped to write it to a ".json" file
`$output = fopen('test.json', 'a');`
and read it from a ".json" file `json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'))`.