# How do you decode a JSON data in WordPress?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, decode

for 8 hours now I have been trying to parse this jSON response data

```
 ﻿{"status":"200","message":"Welcome to spakkolos.com! You are welcome. Stay tuned"}
```

I have tried the followig, no luck:

```
$response = wp_remote_request( "https://loopwi.com/json");
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response); 
$json = json_decode($body);
echo $json->message;  //I got NULL
echo $json['message']; // I got NULL
```

I tried several methods, I explored unserialized function of WordPress - all didn't work. But this works very excellently perfect outside WordPress. I don't know why WordPress made this so difficult a simple process!

I have done many research still no straight forward example. Please guys I need your help?
Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($json);` give?

Comment: var_dump($json);  gives NULL

Comment: @SAMUELADAH Please check my code below and let me know if you face any difficulties

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below code, I have used php file_get_contents instead of wordpress finction, I hope that will make sense to you

```
$body = trim(file_get_contents('https://loopwi.com/json'), "\xEF\xBB\xBF");
$json = json_decode($body);
echo $json->message;  
echo $json['message'];
```

Refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469427/php-file-get-contents-with-json-decode-not-working-together) for explanation

Comment: Your code works, but  `file_get_contents()` is not allowed on WordPress. However, the insight you gave about `trim($response), "\xEF\xBB\xBF");` did the trick and worked. It seems WordPress needs the data trimmed before allowing it to display. I will answer myself and edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your replies. As @Ajith pointed out regarding trim(); by using

```
trim();
```

function on the response body, the problem solves.
There are ways to achieve this:

```
$response = wp_remote_request( "https://loopwi.com/json");
$body = trim(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response), "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); 
$body = trim($body, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); 
$json = json_decode($body);
echo $json->message;
```

Or by this:

```
$url = "https://loopwi.com/json";
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );

if ( is_array( $response ) && ! is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $headers = $response['headers']; // array of http header lines
    $body    = trim($response['body'], "\xEF\xBB\xBF"); // use the content
    $json = json_decode($body);
       echo $json->status; 
       echo $json->message;
}
```

These are functions in the WordPress WordPress's
HTTP API - wp_remote_get, wp_remote_request

Your project may get rejected if you use     file_get_contents() in WordPress. Use the HTTP API functions instead.

Thanks for all those who answered and commented. Cheers!